# How to properly change defcustom prefix key

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

In a [library](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-emacs) I use a prefix key defined like this:

```
(defcustom ensime-mode-key-prefix [?\C-c]
  "The prefix key for ensime-mode commands."
  :group 'ensime-mode
  :type 'sexp)
```

In my config file I've redefined it like the following:

```
(setq ensime-mode-key-prefix [?\C-c ?e])
```

Even though this has changed the prefix, all commands refuse to work with this error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: ensime-mode-key-prefix
```

I've also tried to set it this way:

```
(customize-set-value 'ensime-mode-key-prefix [?\C-c ?e])
```

It also doesn't work, but with a different message - `C-c e is undefined`, which is strange cause in description it's set:

```
ensime-mode-key-prefix is a variable defined in `ensime-vars.el'.
Its value is [3 101]
Original value was [3]
```

I want to change the prefix to `C-c e`, tried to do that with std `kbd`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Sounds like an ensime bug.

Comment: Have you tried using Customize, or the equivalent `(customize-set-value 'ensime-mode-key-prefix ...)` in your init file? I've seen load order issues trying to change default prefix keys for other modes.

Comment: The error makes me wonder if this is connected with the ability to specify prefix keymaps in function slots (but without seeing the code it's impossible to tell).

Comment: @phils I've add the link and made a little update

Comment: Try `customize-set-variable`, not `customize-set-value`.  The former uses the `custom-set` property, if any, for the option; the latter does not. `grep` for that variable in the source code, to see where it is handled. The `defcustom` apparently does not have a `:set` form, but there might be some code somewhere in the library that does handle setting the value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by changing the value of `ensime-mode-key-prefix` you are doing just that and nothing else. Somewhere after the definition of this option there is code which uses the value. If you haven't changed it then the default value is used, else the value you picked.

But if you change the value *after* the library has already been loaded, then that code won't be run again and just changing the variable value won't trigger a change in `ensime-mode-map` (or whatever keymap is relevant here). Such a trigger has to be implemented explicitly using `defcustom`'s `:set` property. And even then this would only have an effect when changing the value through the Custom interface. The `:set` function won't be run if you use `setq`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `customize-set-variable`, not `customize-set-value`. The former uses the `custom-set` property, if any, for the option; the latter does not. `grep` for that variable in the source code, to see where it is handled. The `defcustom` apparently does not have a `:set` form, but there might be some code somewhere in the library that does handle setting the value.